# How do I take 2 tabs from a google sheet and combine based on the 1st column but also sum the 2nd column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, alphabetical-sort

[image: Example]

1st table:

| Company | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A | $100 |
| B | $200 |
| C | $50 |
| D | $100 |

2nd table:

| Company | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A | $50 |
| D | $75 |
| A | $90 |
| D | $100 |
| B | $200 |
| D | $100 |

I want combine the data in a new tab so that all data from company A is combined and the cost is summed. Same for company B, C, D. So in a new tab it would sum up the values for A ($100+$50+$90), B ($200+$200), C ($50), D ($100+$75+$100+$100).
I know I can sort the data myself, but I want it to automatically combine/sum the data so if I add more data to the 1st or 2nd tab, it will already be combined/summed.
I also want it to be able to handle if I add a new random company at anytime.

I tried `SUMIF` but I don't know how to do that with unspecified labels for column A.

This is what I want it to look like in the end, but with it automatically calculating the amounts instead of me typing them in. And I want to be able to add Company E at any time and have it automatically added.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oB92nzVC3Dm9rwLPL-iOedWRc0zsSJYi3xjV9k5xZog/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en). Assuming the first table is in `A2:B` and the second table is in `D2:E`, the formula would be:

```cpp
=QUERY({A2:B;D2:E},"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

Comment: There are on 2 different tabs in one sheet.  Both are in A2:B on there individual tabs.  I want to collect all the data on a new tab so it will give me all the values for A ($100+$50+$90), B ($200+$200), C ($50), D ($100+$75+$100+$100)

Comment: the formula I provided should still work. You just have to adapt the ranges to your data.